# Create Nested Array From Database Self Referencing Table And Show in Nested list In Smarty Template

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, loops

I am getting the rows from database and i am trying to generate an array of the parent categories and its children categories (children can also have children), so that i can pass that array data to my smarty template view and can render check boxes with each category and sub category.

```
Table Categories:

id |      name         | parent_id
 1 |  Electronics      |   0
 2 |  Mobile           |   1
 3 |  iPhone           |   2
 4 |  Men              |   0
 5 |  Shirt            |   4
```

I want the result in such way that those categories with `parent_id = 0` becomes parent and show nested children below it: like this below

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 1 
            [name] => Electronics 
            [children] => Array (
               [0] => Array (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => Mobile
                        [children] => Array (
                                      [0] => Array (
                                             [id] => 3
                                             [name] => iPhone
                                             )
                                      )
                       )
             )
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 4 
            [name] => Men 
            [children] => Array (
               [0] => Array (
                        [id] => 5
                        [name] => Shirt
                       )
             )
 )
```

And this is the code i have written so far:

```
$parentCat = Shopware()->Db()->query("SELECT * FROM `categories`");
    $cats = [];
    foreach ($parentCat->fetchAll() as $key => $value) {
        $prevId = $value['parent_id'];
        if ($prevId == 0) {
            $data = [
                'id' => $value['id'],
                'name' => $value['name']
            ];
            array_push($cats, $data);
        } else {
            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                if($value['parent_id'] == $cat['id']) {
                    $childData = [
                        'id' => $value['id'],
                        'name' => $value['name'],
                    ];
                    array_push($cats,$childData);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($cats);
    die();
```

The Result I am getting is like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Electronics
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Mobile
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => iPhone
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Cars
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => Toyota
    )

)
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the `$tasks` array you pushing into? and notice your current algorithm will only work on 1 level...
It is look like the first  `if` statement return true each time (parent_id == 0) try print it to check why

Comment: @dWinder Yeah i changed that `$tasks` array sorry about that. Also yeah i want it to be nested as much as there are childrens in it. I dont know what wrong am i doing. Completely as lost right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive function like this:

```
function addToArr(&$arr, $data) {
    if ($data["parent_id"] == 0)
        return $arr[] =  ["id" => $data["id"], "name" => $data["name"], "children"=> []];
    foreach($arr as &$e) {
        if ($e["id"] == $data["parent_id"]) { // if found add as child
            $e["children"][] = ["id" => $data["id"], "name" => $data["name"], "children"=> []];
            break;
        }
        addToArr($e["children"], $data); // call recursively 
    }
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/dXOKa)

**Edit**

To have HTML tag:

```
function getHTMLformat($arr) {
    if (!$arr) return "";
    $str = "<ul>" . PHP_EOL; // starting the list 
    foreach ($arr as $e) {
        $str .= "<li>" . $e["name"] . getHTMLformat($e["children"]) . "</li>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $str . "</ul>" . PHP_EOL; // end list
}

echo getHTMLformat($res);
```

Comment: That really works fine without any problem, but i also need to render that to smarty template and create a list from it <h1>All Categories</h1> {foreach $res as $key => $value} <li>{$value.name} {foreach $value['children'] as $child} <li>{$child.name}</li> {/foreach} </li> {/foreach} it goes only to one level. can you please help make it according to array children level ? it would be great help. Thanks

Comment: I can - but better open new post for that - because we want SO to have 1 question per post. Also. make sure to explain the tag needed (`li`, `ul`... in each level).
You can refer this question as starting point

Comment: It says i can only create one question every 90 minutes. i really can't wait that long. I really need to complete this thing asap.

Comment: @Mohsin - added - but hope I made the appropriate tag - as I was not sure what you wanted exactly. At least edit your question so it will be clear what this post try to answer on

Comment: Actually i did mentioned i have to use the data in smarty template. but i also edited question title now to be more clear. And no need to worry about tags i just needed the idea, i'll manage tags. Moreover thank you so much again for the help.